# Pentaho/ PDI-CE 9.0 / UDJC-step fails to execute external Java classes when running in Carte

Tags: java, pentaho, jobs, kettle, pdi

I have created some external functions, saved in jar-files in the /libext-folder, which are used in UDJC steps. In Spoon, everything runs fine. When I run the job with the transformation in Carte, the initialization of the UDJC steps fails:

```
2022/03/31 11:57:36 - TRANSACTION_MAPPER.0 - ERROR (version 9.0.0.0-423, build 9.0.0.0-423 from 2020-01-31 04.53.04 by buildguy) : Error initializing UserDefinedJavaClass:
2022/03/31 11:57:36 - TRANSACTION_MAPPER.0 - ERROR (version 9.0.0.0-423, build 9.0.0.0-423 from 2020-01-31 04.53.04 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:
2022/03/31 11:57:36 - TRANSACTION_MAPPER.0 - null
```

It looks as if the external jar-files cannot be accessed. Any ideas how to solve this?

Other jobs without these extensions execute fine.

I have browsed all available documentation and forums, but did not find any hint.

Thanks for you help - Heiko

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it working :-)

I realized that the start command in file carte.bat is launching spoon.bat, and so I created a copy which launched spoon in debug mode, I already had a batch file spoonWithDebug.bat, where I assigned more RAM, and set the "Xdebug" options which allows my Eclipse IDE to connect to the running Spoon instance and debug my jar-files. Surprisingly, this worked, and my job was executed!

I assume that simply the original Spoon.bat assigns to less RAM for PDI; I know that my Java installation (Amazon Coretto) needs more resources then the original Java product, but that is no longer available for free.